# The argument type '({Column child})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, dart

It worked before, but now it gives this error. What can I do?

> class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

```
appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: Text("SHOP 1!"), // обернуть в padding и задать местоположение

    ),
    body:
    (

    child: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle_rounded,
                  size: 24.0,


                ),
                label: Text('Личный кабинет'),
              ),

            )
        )],
    ),
    )



);
```

}

> }

Answer (score 0):

The open paren right after body is causing this. Delete that and the closing paren on the line by itself before the line with a closing paren and a semicolon.

You are actually accidentally using the new "records" feature of Dart 3.0.  https://dart.dev/language/records

Answer (score 0):

I assume u miss or delete the Container Widget or any other Widget inside the body.

```
body:
    Container(    
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle_rounded,
                  size: 24.0,  

                ),
                label: Text('Личный кабинет'),
              ),    
            )
        )],
    ),
    )
```